# Wallpaperservice / MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, wallpaper

I basically need my main activity to run activity and not wallpaper service

Example: public class SBLiveWallpaper extends WallpaperService { - this is how it is now

This is how I need it: public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Is is possible to make the wallpaper service like secondary or something within the main activity file? Basically have both those lines of codes running but have the extends activity one kind of be the main one.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to run something but it won't work with wallpaperservice but it will work when extends activity is there, when its extends wallpaperservice it won't work, but I need wallpaperservice so the live wallpaper will work, and I need the extends activity so the other component will work